# Batch for rename file extension

Tags: batch-file

I got a folder of 50 images in .jpg and I want them to be .png. But the problem is it renamed the batch file itself which i dont want.
So I write a batch like this but it doesn't work:

```
ren *.* *.png
ren rename.png rename.bat
timeout /t 1
exit
```

Any idea?

Comment: I'm assuming you realize that renaming a file from `jpg` to `png` doesn't *actually* make it `png`, right? If the format isn't png some software might not be able to display them (and the ones that are able to will choose to completely ignore the fact that you named them `png` seeing as they look like `jpg` files)

Comment: renaming the file to png doesn't ***convert*** that to a real png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
ren *.jpg* *.png
ren rename.png rename.bat
timeout /t 1
exit
```

Comment: you can omit the line `ren rename.png rename.bat`, because with `ren *.jpg* *.png`, the batchfile is not affected. Also `ren *.jpg *.png` is sufficient (you don't need `*.jpg*`) Nevertheless, h2o000000 is right, changing the extension doesn't change the format of the file, so just renaming could do more harm than glory.

Comment: Thank Dainius and Stephan, it is easy but i could not think of this.